# How to send a list of lists as query parameter in FastAPI?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI framework and I want to send a list of lists using `Query` parameters. I can send a list using the below syntax, but I am unable to pass list of lists.

```
sections_to_consider: Optional[List[str]] = Query(None)
```

I get the below output.

[image]

What I want is something like this

```
{
  "sections_to_consider": [
    ["string", "string2"],
    ["string3", "string4"]
  ]
}
```

I tried below syntax but getting an error.

```
sections_to_consider: Optional[List[list]] = Query(None)

sections_to_consider: Optional[List[List[str]]] = Query(None)
```

I need to accept list of lists. This is an optional parameter but, if passed, the inner list must have exactly 2 strings.
Is there any way to do it in FastAPI? Or any work around?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As of now, fastApi does not supports nested list from query parameters. you can find more in multiselection lists [Multiselect](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4043) and [dropdownMenu](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/246).

Workaround can be using request body. Instead of sending the List[List[str]] form Query, can send the data by [request body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/)

- either by new class
- or by using [depends](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/)

*Example using class:* `app.py`

```
from typing import List

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class newList(BaseModel):
  sections_to_consider: List[List[str]]

@app.post("/items/")
async def read_items(q: newList):
    return q

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("6:app",host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, reload=True)
```

You can use a `curl request` or `Request URL` and `request body` from OpenApi docs

`curl request`:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "sections_to_consider": [
    ["string", "string2"],
    ["string3", "string4"]
  ]
}'
```

`Request URL`:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/
```

`Request Body`:

```
{
  "sections_to_consider": [
    ["string", "string2"],
    ["string3", "string4"]
  ]
}
```

The Response from the request will be as below:

`ResponseBody`:

```
{
  "sections_to_consider": [
    [
      "string",
      "string2"
    ],
    [
      "string3",
      "string4"
    ]
  ]
}
```